# Why do my speeds fluctuate from decent to unusable while on wireless?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

For the past few weeks, I have been having trouble with my internet. I first diagnosed the problem as being an issue with my wndr3100v2. After getting a new router, wndr3700v4, I noticed the same issues. My speeds would be perfect (30 Mbps down, 5 Mbps up) whenever plugged directly in to the router via ethernet. When I am using wireless, my speeds fluctuate from 20 Mbps (down) to 1 Mbps. After I returned the wndr3700v4, I purchased a belkin n600 db which experienced the same issue. I replaced the ethernet cord from the modem to the router; I can't figure out what the issue is. The next thing I may try is replacing my modem but why would I have perfect speeds when plugged directly in to it but terrible speeds when using wireless? I have done speed tests on other wireless devices so it isn't just my computer. Also, last month my internet worked perfectly and I had no issues so this is a recent issue.

Any help would be amazing. Thanks.

Comment: Other electronics in the house can age and become noisier than they were. A new TV/Mobile channel from your local Tx mast could be interfering. The PSU for the modem could be generating noise. Even old CCBs can introduce noise. Try pulling the plug on everything else in the house. Try changing channel.

Comment: Questions: 1. Is this issue with a laptop? you didn't specify. 2. I know this sounds a little bit dumb, but are you running any applications such as auto downloader apps, or of that nature? 3. Are you a 100% sure this happens on other devices. 4. Is it possible to cause the drop in speeds or is it random? 5. How are you detecting the drop in speed?

Comment: @Tog: The channel is set to auto. What should I change it to? Is there a tool to check for the best channel?

Comment: @Sickest: 1. I am using a desktop with a belkin n600 db adapter. 2. Yes I am but I have checked them all and turned them off even. 3. Yep. Other people in my house complain about the speeds and I have checked with speed tests. 4. Random 5. testmy.net and speedtest.net

Comment: and you have tested 2 different routers for this, and its the same thing?

Comment: @Sickest: 3. wndr3100v2, wndr3700v4, and belkin n600 db.

Comment: This has to be related to your ISP and the modem they provided for you.

Comment: @Sickest: How would I go about getting it replaced? The ethernet speeds are fine.

Comment: do you have DSL or Cable?

Comment: @Sickest: Cable

Comment: @StraightUpT, Usually I would say to leave it on auto but you could try experimenting with other channels.

Comment: @Tog: It has been on auto.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible there is an object nearby causing wireless interference, either your own or a neighbors, within the same band as your wireless broadcast? I'm not sure as to your living situation, but I lived in a house and had no issues with wireless connectivity via my router nor my logitech devices. I moved into a much busier apartment and my wireless devices as well as connectivity suffered and I had to move to a wired solution.

Comment: I live in a suburban area with no nearby apartments. Also, the issue has only started occurring recently even though I haven't moved from this house.